# How to remove parentheses from article year for numeric-comp style (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, parentheses

I am using numeric-comp style. But the year for article has parentheses whereas year for 'incollection' and 'inproceedings' do not.

I am a beginner at LaTeX and would like to remove the parentheses from the article year.

Here is my current code,

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
natbib=true,
%dashed=false,
sorting=none,
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=10,
firstinits=true,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
eprint=false,
defernumbers=true,
abbreviate=false,
style=numeric-comp]{biblatex} 

%-- formatting hell for biblatex
%-- remove "In:"
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
% Add spaces
\setlength\bibitemsep{3.5\itemsep}
%-- no "quotes" around titles of chapters/article titles
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]
{title}{#1}
%-- no punctuation after volume
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]
{volume}{ {#1} } 
%-- puts number/issue between brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]
{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}} 
%-- and then for articles directly the pages w/o any "pages" or "pp." 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]
{pages}{#1}
%-- for some types replace "pages" by "p."
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings, incollection, inbook]
{pages}{p. #1}
%-- format 16(4):224--225 for articles
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
    \printfield{volume}
    \printfield{number}
    \printunit{\addcolon}
}
%-- citations with square brackets (== \usepackage[square]{natbib})
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{
    \begingroup
    \blx@blxinit%
    \blx@setsfcodes%
    \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen%
    \endgroup}
\AtEveryCite{
    \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
    \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
    \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}
\makeatother
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and here is an example of how the types of reference are outputted

> - [8] H. Han, C. Park, J. Heo, and S. K. Kang. Muffler Sound Development Using Analysis of Acoustic Source
>     of Engine Exhaust System. SAE 2014 World Congress & Exhibition. SAE International, 2014.
> - [9] M. Harrison. Interior noise: assessment and control. Vehicle Refinement. Edited by M. Harrison. Oxford:
>     Butterworth-Heinemann, 2004, p. 145 –233.
> - [10] A. Singh, S. Bharadwaj, and S. Narayan. Analysis of Various NVH Sources of a Combustion Engine.
>     Tehniˇcki glasnik 10 (1-2):(2016), 29–37.
> - [11] G. Kwon, H. Jo, and Y. J. Kang. Model of psychoacoustic sportiness for vehicle interior sound: Excluding
>     loudness. Applied Acoustics 136:(2018), 16 –25.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you won't need the block between `\makeatletter...\makeatother` to obtain square brackets around the citation number with the style you use. This is only necessary for `authoryear` and `authortitle`-like styles.

Comment: Okay will make those changes

Comment: You may also want to add a few `%` in `\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864) (if you want spaces, produce them with `\setunit{\addspace}` and friends instead, see §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). A few other things could also be handled more elegantly.

Comment: Thanks @moewe like I said I am only a beginner so I didnt expect my code to be perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

removes the parentheses around the date (and issue) of `@article` and `@periodical`.

Comment: Perfect! Simple code and fast response. Thank you